# UWP XAML isn't live updating for shared project during debug

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now. About a month ago when I debug my UWP app on my local machine it stopped letting me do real time Xaml changes in Visual Studio 2019 v16.5.2. I have three business apps that share most of the code in a Shared Project. Xaml updates on the actual app project work but not on the Shared Project (which is where most of the XAML views are). I've been working on this app for over two years and I've always been able to do it.

I can't find anything online or even other people having this problem. Not even sure what search terms to use. Recompiling for every little Xaml change is driving me nuts

Comment: I found a link to where other people are having the same problem but no solution... https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/889907/uwp-hot-reload-does-not-work-for-xaml-files-in-a-s.html

Comment: What's mean of Xaml updates on the shared project? Do you mean that the xaml could not be updated in xaml designer?

Comment: It doesn't do live hotload changes. usually I can make xaml changes realtime while i'm debugging the app on my local machine. won't do it if the xaml pages are in a shared project, only the main project.

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 works fine, 2019 used to until about a month ago